# Typeorm static method in react native not working

Tags: react-native, expo, typeorm

I'm trying to add a static method to an entity in Typeorm.
I already have this entity:

```
@Entity("accounts")
export class Account extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string

  @Column("text")
  title: string

  @Column("int")
  balance: int
}
```

I want to be able to get the balance of all accounts, with one single method.
So I'm trying to add this:

```
  static async totalBalance() {
    const accounts = await Account.find({}) // this is for example only, not working
    return accounts
  }
```

I added this inside my Account entity, and I'm trying to call it inside other file.

```
const balance = Account.totalBalance()
```

But it is not working and I get the following errors:
[image]

What is wrong with my implementation?
If I return [1,2,3] instead of accounts everything is fine, so I think there's a problem. But how to solve it/why is happening?
Thank you :)

Comment: It seems that something is wrong with using two fetches in the same block of code.
Still don't know why is happening.

Comment: const fetchedAccounts = await Account.find({})
      const fetchedArccounts = await Account.find({})


Using this code will throw the errors i get.